failed to find class org/conscrypt/CryptoUpcalls
I'm trying to read from BigQuery and load it to GCS bucket using spark bigquery connector spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar. I'm able to write to BQ successfully but getting the following error when trying to read. I tried with other version of jar's but still getting the same error.
failed to find class org/conscrypt/CryptoUpcalls
How to resolve this issue?

Please upgrade to the latest version of the connector, version 0.37.0
